# draw canvas 3d rectangle

Tags: android, 3d, android-canvas

I Have extended View class and override draw method. In draw method I draw rectangle using canvas. but this rectangle is simple I need to show as blow.  how can I  draw rectangle like shown in below image?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to have graph like thing?

Comment: I need to show graph like shown in image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) for the top side using 4 points (moveTo and lineTo) and then draw it with [Canvas.drawPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath%28android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Paint%29). Do the same for the right side

Comment: can u give simple example with drawrect and drawline ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for the [HoloGraphLibrary](https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary/wiki/Home). Just check it.

It has no 3d effect as you want but it has Same ui as you want. You will have to play little to have effect like 3d rectangle.

Try a look and let me know if it do not help you.

Enjoy Coding and All The Best.  :)